# Chinese demographic data (age, gender)

Tags: data-request, demographics, population, china

I am on a quest to find areas in China with disproportionate gender and/or age distributions.

I don't really care if these areas are defined by political boundaries.

Since map-making is largely illegal in China, I'm not having a very easy time finding rich, open data sets. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official stats page of China has a table with gender per political region, in Chinese, with the data you are looking for (source is Wikipedia [Sixth National Population Census of the People's Republic of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_National_Population_Census_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China#cite_note-Communique_1-1))

http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/ndsj/renkoupucha/2000pucha/html/t0102.htm

[Google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stats.gov.cn%2Ftjsj%2Fndsj%2Frenkoupucha%2F2000pucha%2Fhtml%2Ft0102.htm)

---

Additionally, the [UN data portal](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=POP&f=tableCode%3a22%3bcountryCode%3a156%3brefYear%3a2010%3bsexCode%3a1%2c2&c=2,3,6,8,10,12,14,15,16&s=_countryEnglishNameOrderBy:asc,refYear:desc,areaCode:asc&v=1) has gender data for China from the 2010 census. You have to select China, 2010, and then with "More filters", select Male and Female. This will give you age and gender groups, but not geographical.

[image]